# Does $\log_1(1)$ have two solutions?

Tags: logarithms

Can the solutions for $\log_1(1)$ be $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Use \log_{1}({1}) (with $$ round it of course)

Comment: well $\log_1(1)$ has infinite solutions consider $\log_1(1) = C\implies 1 = 1^C$ which is true for all $C$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I get it for 1 raced to one and one raced to 0 as well? Thank You!

Comment: Yes , well technically $\log_a(b)$ is not defined for $a =1$ , only for $a\gt1$. But the solution is all reals $\mathbb R$